# Is there a way to output "hello world" in the application output window in Qt Creator when programm is run?

Tags: qt, plugins

I'm trying to make something like plugin that outputs certain text when Qt creator runs any program. Does anyone have any idea what should I use to achieve that?

edit:
I need to make plugin that checks whether user has used appropriate style of programming. (Has put spaces where required for example) But I'm not sure how it is done so I try to start with some simple output while building.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on what sort of text and where you want it? And I think why you need it might help to get the best answer as I'm a bit puzzled why you'd need it for any and every program you've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the debug statements:

```
qDebug() << "some debug info";
qWarning() << "a warning";
```